# Pegar informações de um ObjectJson sem Array

Tags: android, json

Possuo a classe abaixo e que consigo buscar as informações de um JSONArray neste formato:

**{"cliente":[{"id":"1334","nome":"Bruno"}]}**

```
TextView nome_usuario;

private static final String TAG_CLIENTE = "cliente";
private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";

JSONArray cliente = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View grafico = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_perfil, container, false);
    nome_usuario = (TextView ) grafico.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    new JSONParse().execute();
   return grafico;
}


private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Atualizando");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("url do json");
            return json;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            cliente = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTE);
            JSONObject c = cliente.getJSONObject(0);
            String nome = c.getString(TAG_NOME);
            nome_usuario.setText(nome);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

}
```

Porém agora gostaria de trabalhar com um json no seguinte formato:

**{"name":"Bruno"}**

Achei uma duvida semelhante a minha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742944/how-to-parse-json-object-android-studio , porém não consegui aplicar ao meu exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Isolando o código responsável pelo parsing, temos:

```
try {
    cliente = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTE);
    JSONObject c = cliente.getJSONObject(0);
    String nome = c.getString(TAG_NOME);
    nome_usuario.setText(nome);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Se você substituir o retorno do servidor de `{"cliente":[{"id":"1334","nome":"Bruno"}]}` por `{"name":"Bruno"}`, poderá fazer o parsing utilizando apenas as seguintes linhas dentro do bloco `try-catch`:

```
    String nome = json.getString(TAG_NOME);
    nome_usuario.setText(nome);
```

Para implementações futuras, sugiro que você estude a possibilidade de usar bibliotecas como o [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) para fazer essas consultas. Esta em específico poupa você de manipular o JSON, podendo focar nos parâmetros e retornos da chamada HTTP, ambos já serializados/deserializados.

**EDIT:**

Executei o código abaixo em uma unidade de testes do jUnit e o mesmo foi executado com sucesso (trocando o primeiro parâmetro do `assertEquals` faz com que o teste termine com erro, como esperado).

```
@Test
public void decodeJson() throws JSONException {
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"Bruno\"}");
    final String name = json.getString("name");
    assertEquals("Bruno", name);
}
```

O JSON que você está passando como parâmetro deve estar em um formato diferente do que você especificou na pergunta, por isso a `JsonException` está sendo lançada. Você pode utilizar o [depurador](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) ou [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html?hl=pt-br) para descobrir o valor real do seu `JSONObject` e então adaptar o código de acordo.

Comment: Já havia tentado dessa maneira porém é informado:

Comment: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for name

Comment: @BrunoMendonça atualizei a resposta com uma explicação.